# Is it okay for a JUnit test method to throw Exception rather than specific exceptions?

Tags: java, reflection, junit

For example, when using reflection, the test method's header would look something like this:

```
public void validModuleTest() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
```

In this case would it be acceptable to throw Exception? For example:

```
public void validModuleTest() throws Exception {
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*In this case would it be acceptable to throw Exception?*" - Why would you declare that it `throws Exception` if it isn't true?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040920/8200937) might be relevant.

Comment: Why does your unit test use reflection? Tests are supposed to validate input-response pairs through observable API surfaces. Reflection is not an observable API surface.

Comment: Yeah I'm confused about the reflection part too.  Most unit test frameworks have a test runner that uses reflection, but that's code that's already written and tested, so why worry about it?  Just use the test runner and all will be well.  If you're re-inventing the wheel, that's very bad, please don't.

Comment: Why do you care about the declared exceptions of a JUnit test method? You won't call this method yourself, and the test runner can deal with any declaration. If the test throws an exception (no matter what type), it will count as failure anyway. So, if you're too lazy to type the long list (and don't have an IDE that does it for you), you can as well write `throws Exception`.